# How to stop 'You have mail' message in linux.

Tags: apache-http-server, ssh, sendmail

I have sendmail installed. nothing else.
i just logged into my server via SSH and typed..

```
service httpd restart


Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

as you can see on the 3rd line it says i have mail. i do not want to see that message. how can i disable it?

Comment: @jchapa: Not really. Serverfault is for "[computer systems in a **professional** capacity](http://serverfault.com/faq)". Besides, it's perfectly OK to run a mail server for home/development usage. So please read a bit before you suggest stuff.

Answer (score 0):

add `unset MAILCHECK` to your shell's startup file.